# Intercept ajax call in ASP.NET application and log out users under specific conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application using identity and entity.
An administrator can enable/disable a user. what I want to acheive is, if a user is already connected to the application and the Admin disables him/her (through setting a flag in that user record (disabled = true), then that user should be logged out.
I'm not looking for the admin to log the user by themselves, but rather to have it done on the user side on the next ajax call.
I have tried using the events provided in global.asax.cs file (`protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)`), but calling the log out on the controller:

```
 Session.Abandon();
 Session.RemoveAll();
 AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
```

is resulting in an exception saying that Session is null.

Could anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use cookie authentication, you can just invalidate their cookie and be done with it:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // important to register UserManager creation delegate. Won't work without it
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(UserManager.Create);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
                .OnValidateIdentity<UserManager, ApplicationUser, int>(validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        },
        // other configurations
    });

    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hill for directing me towards this solution.

Comment: I have used the security stamp update in order to log out another user.